# Running a pytest test from a python file and NOT from a command line

Tags: python, pytest

I have three python files in one directory (c:\Tests), I am trying to run the test using pytest from the file TestCases1.py but I have not succeed. I am new to python and I do not know if I am asking the right question. I have seen several examples but almost all use the command line to run the test and I want to run them from a python file. Since I am newbie to testing, I would appreciate a very simple answer (I have seen some similar questions but I did not get the answers). I am using Python 36-32 and Eclipse Oxygen 3a.

**min_max.py** => Some basic functions to be tested

```
def min(values):
    _min = values[0]
    for val in values:
        if val < _min:
            _min = val
    return _min

    

def max(values):
    _max = values[0]
    for val in values:
        if val > _max:
            _max = valal
    return _max
```

**min_max_test.py**  => Some tests for the functions

```
import min_max

def test_min():
    print("starting")
    values = (2, 3, 1, 4, 6)
    val = min(values)
    assert val == 1
    print("done test_min")


def test_max():
    print("starting")
    values = (2, 3, 1, 4, 6)
    val = max(values)
    assert val == 6
    print("done test_max")
```

**TestCases1.py** => File from where I want to run the test

```
import pytest
pytest_args = [
    'c:\Tests\min_max_test.py'
]

pytest.main(pytest_args)
```

Comment: Why do you want to run the tests from a Python file?

Comment: I honestly would like to hear why not, why it is always from command line.

Comment: I hate when people on SO question your question... "why do you want to do that?", "why not do this?". if you don't know the answer to the question itself, please stay silent. please don't answer a different question that I didn't ask

Answer (score 2):

Optionally, you could use `subprocess` to run pytest commands on your python script. For example,

```
# ~/tests
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["pytest . -q"], shell=True)
>>>
.                                                                                             [100%]
1 passed in 0.00s
CompletedProcess(args=['pytest . -q'], returncode=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `min_max_test.py`, the `min` and `max` variable names in the test functions would be taken from the built-ins and not from your min_max.py file.

You either need to use something like `min_max.min` or import those functions using a `from` import rather than a full module import.

P.S. please include the error messages along with the questions and be specific as to what problem you are having. makes it that much easier :)

Comment: It worked!, thank you very much. I also have to comment that for notice that is working I have to force a wrong assert! I do not have enough reputation to vote up though!!